# VBA - I need VLookUP-ish code for copying values

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks. One of them `wb1` consists `client` names in column A, and a `idnumber` in column B. The other workbook `wb2` also have the same `client` names in columb A (but in different order). What i need to do is to copy the `idnumbers` from `wb1`and paste to the second workbook using the `client` name as reference. The copied values must go to the column (ie. J, AC, DC)specifed by the user (using inputbox), and the macro should paste the values only if the target cell is not already populated by the `idnumber`.

Im not sure how to use the application.vlookup method and if its the right way or there are simplier methods.

Id like to hear your advices

So far i managed to came up with this

```
Sub copy_val()
Dim lookfor As Range, lookin As Range, found As Variant, col as variant


Set lookfor = Workbooks("wb1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:a22")
Set lookin = Workbooks("wb2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:a22")

col = InputBox("please provide input colum")
found = apllication.VLookup(lookfor.Value, lookin, col, 0)


For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Range("B2:b21")
Range("B&Activecell.row").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("found").Select
Selection.Paste


End Sub
```

I also used this one but i dont know why i cant get proper adress of cell using:

```
col = inputbox("please provide input column"
id_row = sheets.("sheet2).range("col"&"2").row
id_col = sheets.("sheet2).range("col"&"2").column
```

Comment: Start by posting the code you have.

Comment: (See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're curious about why you may have received downvotes.)

Comment: @Miqi180 i edited the post to show you my code

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you are seeking for.

```
Sub VLookupUDF()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim col As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(<source sheet name>)
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(<sheet name for vlookup>)
wb.Activate

Set rng = ws.Range("A:B")
ws1.Select

col = InputBox("please provide input colum")

For Each cl In ws1.Range("B2:b21")

If ws1.Cells(cl.Row, CStr(col)).Value = "" Then
ws1.Cells(cl.Row, col).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & cl.Address & "," & rng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & rng.Address & ",2,0)"
ws1.Cells(cl.Row, col).copy
ws1.Cells(cl.Row, col).pastespecial xlpastevalues

End If

Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats a nice code i can work on. 
This piece:
`Cells(cl.Row, col).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & cl.Address & "," & rng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & rng.Address & ",2,0)"` literally adds a formula in that cell, but i would need actual value instead of formula inside the cell

Also the code provided by you looks for the value in the target sheet instead of source sheet (thats why i get "N/A" errors in the cell). But i gues i can change it by myself with some tweaks to fit my case.

Comment: Insert the sheet names instead of index while setting ws & ws1. copy and pasting cell as value at the same location will help you get the value instead of formula. Please check the updated version of answer.

Comment: all those `Cells` references need a worksheet object before them

Comment: yeah you are right. I made the corrections.. Thanks @Brad

Comment: @AdityaPansare I think i made my final code with your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Aditya Pansare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6887294/aditya-pansare/) and some tweaks to fit my case I have found the complete solution.

```
Sub VLookupUDF()

Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim col As String

Set wb1 = Workbooks("wb1.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("wb2.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Data table")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Reg input")



wb1.Activate
Set rng = ws1.Range("A:B")
wb2.Activate
ws2.Select

col = InputBox("Please provide input column")

For Each cl In ws1.Range("A2:A21")

If ws2.Cells(cl.Row, CStr(col)).Value = "" Then
ws2.Cells(cl.Row, col).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & cl.Address & ",'[wb1.xlsm]Data table'!$A:$B,2,0)"
ws2.Cells(cl.Row, col).Copy
    With ws2.Cells(cl.Row, col)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    End With


End If

Next cl
MsgBox ("Export completed")
End Sub
```